# Asking user to download file in PHP

Tags: php, download

I am trying to get the browser to prompt the user to download a file. However, after having tried several methods from stack overflow and around the Internet, for some reason all are silently failing. Is it the case that this just isn't possible in modern browsers?

I'm simply wanting the user to download a text (.txt) file from the server. I've tried this code below (and more) to no avail:

```
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=newfile.txt');
header('Content-type: text/plain');
readfile('newfile.txt');
```

.

```
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");

$file = $_GET["file"] .".txt";
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . urlencode($file));   
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");            
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));
flush(); // this doesn't really matter.
$fp = fopen($file, "r");
while (!feof($fp))
{
    echo fread($fp, 65536);
    flush(); // this is essential for large downloads
} 
fclose($fp);
```

I have tried the examples from PHP.NET (none of which are working for me):
http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

I have the correct permissions set, the file exists and is_readable. I'm now left scratching my head as to why this isn't working. Any help would be great.

Comment: Are you saying that you are unable to read the file?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I'm able to read the file on the server, the issue is I want it to prompt the user to download the file. Currently this isn't happening.

Comment: I tried to help you out with a solution check if that helps you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have one solution for you.

Lets assume `download.php` is the file that downloads the file.

So when the user clicks on the link to download show a confirm dialog, if the user selects yes then re direct the user to `download.php` or else download will not occur some browsers like chrome starts the download without asking users if they like to download a file or not.

Comment: The issue is though that I'm stuck on actually getting the file from the browser to the user. No matter what code I use, the browser is refusing to download the file. :(

The user clicks a "generate file" button, the server generates a file (I have this working), I just need it to be downloaded by the user now. Could this issue be with my use of Ajax?

Comment: Nope you should not use ajax but redirect the user directly to that page

Comment: Thanks, I quickly pulled the Ajax out of my application and it appears to be working :)

Comment: Glad that i helped you.